# how can i run oc login and oc rollout using github action?

Tags: openshift, github-actions, cicd, openshift-client-tools

here are my some of the workflow steps and last one is failing

```
    - name: Install oc
      uses: redhat-actions/openshift-tools-installer@v1
      with:
        oc: 4.10 

    # https://github.com/redhat-actions/oc-login#readme
    - name: Log in to OpenShift
      uses: redhat-actions/oc-login@v1
      with:
        openshift_server_url: ${{ env.OPENSHIFT_SERVER }}
        openshift_token: ${{ env.OPENSHIFT_TOKEN }}
        insecure_skip_tls_verify: true
        namespace: ${{ env.OPENSHIFT_NAMESPACE }}

    - name: Deploy new image as rollout
      run: oc rollout latest dc/asenion-app
```

unable to find out any GitHub action in github marketplace to run "oc rollout" or other openshift cli commands

Comment: How is it failing? Is there an error message?

Comment: It is resolved the issue is in the Github action output which give error at the end of the pipeline. -- thanks you to mention the 'error message' which make me think about it.